# Auth0 & vue.js appState.target not working across multiple domains

Tags: vue.js, oauth-2.0, vuejs3, auth0

Currently I'm setting up a project that uses vue.js in the frontend and integrates Auth0 for authentication.

The target strucuture is that I have kind of a landingpage from where the user logs in and then there are a set of small web applications that run on multiple subdomains.
(e.g. app1.example.com, app2.example.com, etc.)

In my local dev environment I'm running the different applications inside multiple docker containers and I access them using localhost with different ports. (e.g. localhost:8080 for the landingpage, localhost:8081 for app1 and localhost:8082 for app2)

What I want to achive is that, when a user logs in on the landingpage he is redirected to a certain subpage of app1.

While the Login itself and the redirect to the app1 is working, the last part with redirecting to a specific subpage is not working.

According to the documentation you have to set appState.target as parameter for the loginWithRedirect() method from the auth0 library.
I did that but it still always redirects to the root page (/) after the callback.

To verify the issue is only when switching from the landingpage to app1 I changed the configuration of Auth0 to redirect back to the landingpage after login and in that case it also redirected me to the defined subpage.

So the issue only exists when switching the domain (the port in my case).

Did I miss some configuration or is it just not working that way?

Answer (score 0):

this Auth0 documentation says you need to specify the Callback URL. You can read more here https://community.auth0.com/t/allow-multiple-custom-domains-for-multitenant-applications/64319